Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaApplicationInfoManager'
Trying to run spring cloud gateway in AWS fargate and encountering below issue.
JDK 17,
Spring boot 3.1.2
Below is the log.
1734432268120,Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
1734432268161,"2024-12-17T16:14:28.153+05:30 ERROR [apigateway-service,,] 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed"
1734432268161,org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:357) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:156) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:124) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:611) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar!/:3.1.2]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar!/:3.1.2]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar!/:3.1.2]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar!/:3.1.2]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar!/:3.1.2]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar!/:3.1.2]
1734432268161,  at com.example.ApigatewayApplication.main(ApigatewayApplication.java:25) ~[classes!/:13.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
1734432268161,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
1734432268161,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
1734432268161,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
1734432268161,  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569) ~[na:na]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[CloudExample-exec.jar:13.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[CloudExample-exec.jar:13.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[CloudExample-exec.jar:13.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[CloudExample-exec.jar:13.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
1734432268161,"Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaApplicationInfoManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager]: Factory method 'eurekaApplicationInfoManager' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke ""java.lang.CharSequence.toString()"" because ""replacement"" is null"
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:659) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:647) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:375) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.0.2.jar!/:4.0.2]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:179) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.0.2.jar!/:4.0.2]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:362) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getInfo(<generated>) ~[eureka-client-2.0.0.jar!/:2.0.0]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:53) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.0.1.jar!/:4.0.1]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.0.1.jar!/:4.0.1]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.0.1.jar!/:4.0.1]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:179) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  ... 21 common frames omitted
1734432268161,"Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager]: Factory method 'eurekaApplicationInfoManager' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke ""java.lang.CharSequence.toString()"" because ""replacement"" is null"
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  ... 38 common frames omitted
1734432268161,"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke ""java.lang.CharSequence.toString()"" because ""replacement"" is null"
1734432268161,  at java.base/java.lang.String.replace(String.java:2961) ~[na:na]
1734432268161,  at com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$Builder.setStatusPageUrl(InstanceInfo.java:623) ~[eureka-client-2.0.0.jar!/:2.0.0]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory.create(InstanceInfoFactory.java:58) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.0.1.jar!/:4.0.1]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaApplicationInfoManager(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:331) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.0.1.jar!/:4.0.1]
1734432268161,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
1734432268161,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
1734432268161,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
1734432268161,  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569) ~[na:na]
1734432268161,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
1734432268161,  ... 39 common frames omitted

Here is my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>CloudExample</artifactId>
    <version>13-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-eureka-two</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.13</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.goterl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lazysodium-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.23</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>micro</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--  <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
                             <outputDirectory>${appserver.home}/${project.name}-${project.version}</outputDirectory> -->
                            <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
                            <outputDirectory>${appserver.home}/${project.name}</outputDirectory>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.12.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>webapp</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
                <spring-boot.repackage.skip>true</spring-boot.repackage.skip>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src\main\resources</directory>
                        <targetPath>${project.basedir}/target/${project.name}-${project.version}</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.properties</include>
                            <include>*.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src\main\resources</directory>
                        <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.properties</include>
                            <include>*.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
   
</project>

This is working fine in local env but not in AWS fargate. Is there any other custom configuration to do? Please help to resolve this.
Also is there anything to remove or add in POM? Since it is not working
